# Django retrieve rows for the distinct column values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to query Model rows in Django,

```
class Language(models.Model):
    language_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="")
```

In this table, the `language_id` is not unique, for example, below is the sample data

```
+-------------+------+---------+
| language_id | code | name    |
+-------------+------+---------+
|       12345 | en   | english |
|       12345 | te   | telugu  |
|       54321 | en   | english |
|       54321 | te   | telugu  |
+-------------+------+---------+
```

I want to filter the rows(all columns) which should have distinct `language_id`s.

What currently I am doing.

```py
language_list = Language.objects.all()

list = []
idlist = []

for language in language_list:
    if language.language_id not in idlist:
        il = language
        list.append(il)
        idlist.append(language.language_id)
```

Then `list` will have all the distinct rows(model objects).

Is there any better way to do this. I don't want to rotate through all the `language` models.

Comment: I'm confused at the use case, if you want only one row out of multiple rows with the same id aren't you arbitrarily picking one rows data over another? Is that what you want?

Getting a distinct list of just the ids can be done though Language.objects.values_list('language_id', flat=True).distinct()

Though the first occurrence of each id I'm not sure if that's supported via a queryset method.

Comment: The table language contains a foreign key of another model,  the table also contains extra columns. But I have removed them for the sake of simplicity. I need the whole row, not just the ids column.

Answer (score 4):

It's unclear what you are trying to do.
What your script does is take the first occurrence of a given ID arbitrarily.
If that's what you want, it will depend on what database your model is based.
PostgreSQL allows the use of distinct on a field:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

On MySQL what you could do is get all the unique instances of your id and get an instance of your model matching once per ID:

```
language_ids = Language.objects.values_list('language_id', flat=True).distinct()
result = []
for language_id in language_ids:
    result.append(Language.objects.filter(language_id=language_id).first())
```

It's not necessarily much better than your solution simply because arbitrary picking isn't an expected use case for the ORM.

If on the other hand you meant to only get language_ids that appear once and only once:

```
Language.objects.values('language_id').annotate(cnt=Count('id')).filter(cnt=1)
```